# Extra column/field on IdentityUserRoles table using Identity 2 and Entity Framework 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I'm using a custom implementation of the IdentityUser class in my project.
The problem is that Entity Framework adds an extra column in the table **IdentityUserRoles**, mapping the child class Id as a constraint.
 I know that EF is probably getting confused on figuring how to map the relationship with this new class, I just don't know why and how to solve it. I've been searching the web about this EF behavior, but couldn't find a solution yet.

Here are some screenshots that summarize the problem:

[image: UsuarioClass]
[image: DefaultContext]
[image: DefaultCotextModelCreating]
[image: UsuarioFuncaoScheme]
[image: UsuarioMap]

Comment: What exactly is your goal, a user/role table needs 2 foreign keys but you already know that, is Entity making a third colunm that is the user/role id and you don't want that?

Comment: Oh, sorry if it wasn't clear enough...
This extra column shouldn't exist, it seems to be a problem with EF mapping. I want to know how to extend the IdentityUser class without creating that extra field in the many to many table (IdentityUserRoles)

Comment: So you would like the primary key of that table to be the combination of the tow foreign key, rather then having this other useless column as an id of that many to many table. Can't you just delete it AFTER the mapping ? That is what i did but it dosen't seems to be the same framework, i use 4.0

Comment: If I just use Identity with the default configuration, that table will have only the UserId and RoleId as primary key not that useless column like you have well said. 
I'd rather figure out how EF is messing up my mapping (or if I'm messing up something) and fix it properly. I refuse to accept that this is the default behavior of EF and Identity. I'm using EF 6.1.3 and Identity 2.2.1 btw

Comment: Unfortunately... EF tends to always be wanting to add a specific column as the id of the table itself, I saw that behavier many time and desparate trys to prevent it as brougth me nowhere. If you ever find something PLEASE TELL ME.

Comment: Ok then, I'll keep searching for answers... 
Meanwhile, if you don't mind I'd like to  see your alternative to remove that column.

Comment: Well it's not pretty, exept deleting it rigth in the edmx file... Just pick it up, delete it everytime you map your database, if you're tired of that, you can add a  sql update / drop column statement throught your code that does it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I've rechecked my database mappings, and I think I have found a solution for this problem:

My user class mapping was located in another file (UsuarioMap), that inherited from EntityTypeConfiguration, and then I would specify my configurations in its constructor, exactly like the image in the post. (IMHO this is better for code organization). Now my IdentityUser (Usuario) table configuration it's simply located inside the **OnModelCreating** method:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>().ToTable("Usuario");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>().Property(u => u.UserName).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>().Property(u => u.Email).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>().Property(u => u.PasswordHash).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>().Property(u => u.Nome).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>().Property(u => u.DataRegistro).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>().Property(u => u.UltimoLogin).IsOptional();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>().HasOptional(u => u.Cliente).WithMany(c => c.Usuarios);
```

I honestly don't know why Entity Framework look at this two configurations paths differently since the parameter of **modelBuilder.Configurations.Add()** and the return of **modelBuilder.Entity()** is a **System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.EntityTypeConfiguration** object, so logically both ways should work.

Comment: Yeah ! Logicaly, it should have worked from the beginning, Entity should never put an additionnal id column on a many to many table... That's weird really...

Answer (score 0):

Cannot supply a full technical explanation but I made these changes in my code to overcome the problem:

```
public class ResultzContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ResultzContext()
            : base("ResultzConnection")
        {

        }


        static ResultzContext()
        {
            // Set the database intializer which is run once during application start
            // This seeds the database with admin user credentials and admin role
            Database.SetInitializer<ResultzContext>(new ApplicationDbInitializer());
        }

        public static ResultzContext Create()
        {
            return new ResultzContext();
        }
```

:
:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
                //modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id).ToTable("AspNetRoles");
//modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("AspNetUsers");
                modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("AspNetUsers");
                //modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey(l => new { l.UserId, l.LoginProvider, l.ProviderKey }).ToTable("AspNetUserLogins");
                //modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId }).ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");
                //modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("AspNetUserClaims");
```

So, generally commented out everything and changed from IdentityUser to ApplicationUser. But need to add that I originally had code for Identity 1.0
Hope it can help you!

Comment: Actually is not quite the same problem... 
I've seen people mapping/renaming both IdentityUser and the custom class (ApplicationUser in your case) using the model builder. 
In that case makes sense that EF maps it wrong as both tables would serve the same purpose, but in my case I only map the derived class (Usuario). Seems a bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the same issue. There is a much simpler solution. You should explicitly define the relation on the IdentityUserRole configuration.

E.g.:

```
public class UserRoleConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<UserRole>
{
    public UserRoleConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(x => new {x.UserId, x.RoleId});
        HasRequired(x => x.User).WithMany(x => x.Roles).WillCascadeOnDelete();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd completely forgotten this problem. Nowadays I just rather use vanilla cookie authentication then Identity framework. It's just better for me not to have this extra layer for both simplicity and control over my auth logic.